# How to create zsh/bash macro with partial arguments

Tags: bash, zsh

I'd like to create some functions/aliases in my `.zshrc` to help with git, but I'm not sure how.

First one:

Full command: `git commit -s -m "My message"`

My desired end result: `gsc -m "My message"`

Second one:

Full command: `git commit -s -a -m "My message"`

My desired end result: `gsca "My message"`

As you can see I want a macro that would call something with partial arguments and accept all other arguments whatever they may be from this macros call.

What I tried:

1. `function gsc() { git commit -s $@; }`
2. `alias gsc='git commit -s'`

Neither of those worked.

My test:

```
> gsc -a -m "test"
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    smth.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track
```

Comment: The alias in (2) seems normal enough to me, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @muru I added to the question what happened. Basically it didn't read the -a and -m flags and the commit message

Comment: Hmm? Your example doesn't show that. The output doesn't show any changes that would be added by `-a`.

Comment: The alias/function definition is correct, but as git says: "nothing added to commit". Did you forget to run `git add` first?

Comment: Just to be sure: Is the alias activated / did you re-sourece teh rc-file after changes? (use `alias` and see if it is listed)

Comment: Yes, I closed/reopened my terminal and it's resourced. The `-a` should have worked because if I just do `git commit -s -a -m "My message"` directly, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
function gsc() { git commit -s $@; }
```

the use of the *unquoted* `$@` means that any arguments to the function will go through word splitting, and e.g. the call `gsc -m "hello there"` will end up calling `git` with the arguments `commit`, `-s`, `-m`, `hello`, and `there`, i.e. with what was supposed to be commit message split to distinct arguments, as if you'd ran `git commit -s m hello there` on the shell command line.

You need to quote the expansion as `"$@"`. Also, `function foo` is a ksh-ism, that would work equivalently with the standard `foo()`. So:

```
gsc() { git commit -s "$@"; }
```

---

On the other hand, the alias

```
alias gsc='git commit -s'
```

looks like it should work. An alias only substitutes its contents before the command line is parsed, so `gsc -m "hello there"` should be exactly equivalent to `git commit -s -m "hello there"`.

Though you might want to make sure you don't have both the alias and the function defined at the same time when testing. That would surely cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct and the test demonstrates that it works as expected. You should see that it indeed works as expected by typing the full command alongside the short command and verifying that you get the same results. In other words, after running `gsc -a -m "test"` and seeing "nothing added to commit", run `git commit -s -a -m "test"` and verify that it behaves the same way.

I suggest going with an alias rather than a function. Firstly, it'll allow completions to work automatically. Secondly, you'll avoid common mistakes such as missing double quotes around `$@` -- the mistake present in your `gsc` function.